# ngZone is undefined - Injection failure inside Injectable AOT mode only

Tags: angular

I am experiencing a weird issue.

I have a `NotificationService` that calls Bootstrap notify to show some growl style messages.  I am trying to inject `ngZone` in the constructor.  This works in JIT mode but fails in AOT mode with a "cannot call `runOutSideAngular()` of undefined".  Further debugging reveals that the constructor injection is failing in AOT mode but is injected fine in Dev (JIT) mode.

However, I am also injecting `ngZone` in my app.component.ts and it's injected here just fine in both AOT and JIT.

btw, the Service is loaded as a provider in the root module.  I am not able to figure out why the Injection is failing.  I've also tried explict injection using @Inject(NgZone) and also trying to defer the injection using a forwardRef to no avail.

In Dev/JIT:

[image: In Dev/JIT mode]
In Prod/AOT:

[image: In AOT mode]

Here is my NotificationService:

```
  export namespace Notification {
  @Injectable()
  export class NotificationService {
    notifier: any;

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
      console.log('message from NotificationService constructor ngZone is ', this.ngZone);
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: no ideas here??

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who wants to know the issue that caused this - it was due to Namespaces.  For whatever reason injection does not work if the class is within a Namespace.  Not sure if this is an issue with Angular itself.  I had to remove the namespace after which injection worked as normal - not ideal as I wanted to use Namespaces but I can live with it.